# MVC SportsStore: systems.ArgumentException unhandled by user code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, argumentexception

```
public class SqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
   private Table<Product> productsTable;
   public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
   {
       **productsTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Product>();
   }
   public IQueryable<Product> Products
   {
       get { return productsTable; }
   }
}
```

this is an SportsStore example from pro asp.net book (here is a [github link](https://github.com/mgroves/SportsStore) to the source code).  when i run the code it shows system.ArgumentException error. Can anyone tell me what exactly this error is and how can i fix it?
**error shows in the bold area.**

error: Keyword not supported: metadata"

connectionstring:

SQLRepository:

public class SqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
       private Table productsTable;

```
  public SqlProductsRepository(string connectionString)
   {
       productsTable = (new DataContext(connectionString)).GetTable<Product>();
   } 

   public IQueryable<Product> Products
   {
       get { return productsTable; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, connectionString is not set properly.

> The connection string is parsed immediately after being set. If errors in syntax are found when parsing, a runtime exception, such as ArgumentException, is generated. Other errors can be found only when an attempt is made to open the connection.

More information is available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: the connection string looks fine for me. i have no clue why this error shows up

Comment: Are you able to post your connection string here?

Comment: i posted my connection string.

Comment: <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppDb" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>